# how to control visibility in android?

Tags: android, adapter, visible

how to control visibility in android?

if the user does not upload a photo, the ImageView will gone. In contrast, if the user has upload the photo the ImageView will visible.

so how can I do?

this is my xml code.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/infophoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_pic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/expic"
                android:transitionName="sharedView"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my adapter code.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
glide.load(newFeedModels.get(position).getFeedimageURL()).into(holder.uploader_pro_pic);
glide.load(newFeedModels.get(position).getFeedPostImageURL()).into(holder.post_pic);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
post_pic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_pic);
}
```

this is homefragment code.

```
String TAG_FeedMediaPhoto_URL = "FeedPostPhoto";
newFeedModel.setFeedimageURL(json.getString(TAG_FeedMediaPhoto_URL));
```

I need to modify where code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the First step is to check whether this particular item having pic or not

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    
   
        
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(newFeedModels.get(position).getFeedPostImageURL())){
        holder.post_pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        glide.load(newFeedModels.get(position).getFeedPostImageURL()).into(holder.post_pic);
        }else{
            holder.post_pic.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have other question.

if(newFeedModel.getFeedGroupID() != "10"){
            //holder.group_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tv_uploader_group.setText(newFeedModel.getFeedGroupName());
        }else{
            //holder.group_check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_uploader_group.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

the values is 10, but the tv_uploader_group still display

Comment: A question can't have question. Open a new Question and tag me @Stanley

Answer (score 0):

The `android:visibility="invisible"` command controls the visibility of the imageview section.

By using:`imageview.setVisibility(View.visible);` you can change the visibility of the imageview.